# presionar un boton en imacros usando javascript si su id es diferente

Tags: javascript, imacros

Estaba intentando hacer un pequeño javascript para presionar un boton que cambia de id, es decir cada vez que recargo la pagina el boton cambia de id pero nunca me lo presiona. el codigo es el siguiente:

```
var string = '';
var letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','Ñ','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
var init_macro = "CODE:";
init_macro += "VERSION BUILD=9052613" + "\n";
init_macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
for(i = 0; i < 54; i++){
string += letters[i];

init_macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=letters{{string}}*" + "\n";
iimPlay(init_macro);
}
```

El botón suele empezar por una letra y le pongo un asterisco seguido de la combinacion de letras que tenga pero nunca selecciona mi boton.

Comment: No veo en tu código ningún botón, ni ninguna función que intente presionarlo.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo reproducible del código que tienes actualmente?